# Advantages of ShingleFilter\n-GramTokenizer?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have been using standard Analyzer for indexing and searching in Lucene. I recently came across Shingles (2 word shingles\bigrams)and the only advantage I found so far in my research, is that phrase searches will be faster.
On the downside, my index size increased.
I am not very sure what are the real advantages\features my application would benefit by using Shingles.
How would it affect my other existing searches (Stem\Fuzzy etc. Searches) if I index by tokenizing my documents using Shingles/NGramTokenizer?

Can somebody please shed some light on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

It won't affect your other searches, however the size of index will be very large compared to the one indexed using Standard Analyzer.